# Duplicate Count of Details from Master

Tags: apex, trigger

I am writing a trigger on a child (M-D relationship) where if the child object had duplicate records, update the count of duplicate on the Master. The duplicate child is determined if there is a lookup field match. The Lookup field here is Itm__c

The specific issue that I am stuck is
inv.Duplicate__c = inv.Invce_lns__r.size();

This returns me list of all the child records on the Master. How will I be able to just have count of duplicates, I mean after the map.

Here is the code:

```
trigger DuplicateInvceLns on Invce_Lne__c (before insert,before update,after insert, After Delete, After Undelete) {

    Set<Id> setInvceIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> ivtmp = new Set<Id>();
    Map<Id,Invce_Lne__c> inl = new Map<Id,Invce_Lne__c>();


    for(Invce_Lne__c iv : Trigger.new){
        ivtmp.add(Invce__c);
    }

    for(Invce_Lne__c invcelne : [select Id,Name,Itm__c, Invce__c from Invce_Lne__c where Invce__c IN : ivtmp])
        inl.put(invcelne.Itm__c, invcelne);


        for(Invce_Lne__c invcelne : Trigger.new)
        {
            if(invl.containsKey(invcelne.Itm__c)){
                 if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUndelete){
            setInvceIds.add(invcelne.Invce__c);
            system.debug(invcelne.Invce__c);
            system.debug(setInvceIds);
                 }
        }

           else if(Trigger.isDelete){
           setInvceIds.add(invcelne.Invce__c); 
           system.debug(setInvceIds); 
        }
    }
    List<Invce__c> lstInvce = [Select Id,name, (select id from Invce_Lns__r) from Invce__c where Id IN :setInvceIds];
    for(Invce__c inv : lstInvce)
    {
        inv.Duplicate__c = inv.Invce_lns__r.size();
        system.debug(inv.OrderApi__Invoice_lines__r.size());
    }
    update lstInvce;
}
```

Comment: So, if there is more than one child pointing to the same Itm__c, it is a duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a simple aggregate query:

```
trigger DuplicateInvceLns on Invce_Lne__c (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    // Initialize invoice map/Aggregate Invoice Ids
    Map<Id, Invce__c> invoices = new Map<Id, Invce__c>();
    if(Trigger.new != null) {
        for(Invce_Lne__c record: Trigger.new) {
            invoices.put(record.Invce__c, new Invce__c(Id=record.Invce__c, Duplicate__c=0));
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.old != null) {
        for(Invce_Lne__c record: Trigger.old) {
            invoices.put(record.Invce__c, new Invce__c(Id=record.Invce__c, Duplicate__c=0));
        }
    }
    // Query for duplicates
    for(AggregateReult result: [
        SELECT COUNT(Id) dups, Itm__c itemId, Invce__c invoiceId
        FROM Invce_Lne__c
        WHERE Invce__c = :invoices.keySet()
        GROUP BY Itm__c, Invce__c
        HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
    ]) {
        // Increment Duplicate counter
        invoices.get((Id)result.get('invoiceId')).Duplicate__c +=
            ((Decimal)result.get('dups')) - 1;
    }
    // Update records
    update invoices.values();
}
```

I typically refer to this pattern as the Aggregate-Query-Update pattern.

Note that this trigger doesn't consider the first Itm__c a duplicate (hence, the `- 1` in the code). You can remove this if you like, although I find this nomenclature confusing (there is only one duplicate if you have two of an item).